# MySQL select unique months when discounts are valid

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database containing discounts. A simplified version looks like this:

```
id  | start (UNIX timestamp) | end (UNIX timestamp)
45  | 1384693200             | 1398992400  
68  | 1386018000             | 1386277200  
263 | 1388530800             | 1391209200
```

A discount can last a few days, a few months, or even a few years. I'm looking for a way to select a unique list of months where (future) discounts are valid.

If there is:

- a discount which starts in november 2013 and ends in april 2014
- a discount which starts in december 2013 and ends in the same month
- a discount which starts in january 2014 and ends one month later
- a discount which starts in june 2014 and ends the same month

The output should be:

```
- December (2013)  
- January (2014)  
- February (2014)  
- March (2014)  
- April (2014)  
- June (2014)
```

November 2013 is not shown because it is in the past. May 2014 is not shown because there is no discount in that month.

Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shall we just do the whole thing in yyyy-mm-dd for now? My UNIX brain is a little slow.

Comment: Here... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: @Strawberry as Hituptony mentioned, I can easily use FROM_UNIXTIME, so if you have a solution with datetime, I'm all ears :) Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't november 2013 appearing in the desired output?

Comment: Because it is currently December and we only want future discounts. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to handle the logic of intermediate months at the application level, or construct a calendar utility table of all dates.

Comment: @fedorqui's right btw. If you want to amend/clarify the brief, do so in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table containing a sequence of numbers from 0 to a number of month you could ever require, and join this table to your table.
This is example how to get a list of years+months separately for each `id`

```
SELECT id,
       year( start + interval x month ) year,
       month( start + interval x month ) month
FROM
numbers n
JOIN
(
     SELECT id,
            from_unixtime( start ) start,
            from_unixtime( end ) end
     FROM Table1
) q
ON n.x <= period_diff( date_format( q.end, '%Y%m' ),date_format( q.start, '%Y%m' ))
ORDER BY id, year, month ;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7cfc/4

If you want to combine years+months for all `id`, skip `id` column and use GROUP BY

```
SELECT year( start + interval x month ) year,
       month( start + interval x month ) month
FROM
numbers n
JOIN
(
     SELECT id,
            from_unixtime( start ) start,
            from_unixtime( end ) end
     FROM Table1
) q
ON n.x <= period_diff( date_format( q.end, '%Y%m' ),date_format( q.start, '%Y%m' ))
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month ;
```

If you want to skip past years and months, add `WHERE year >= current year AND month >= current month`, this is a trivial change. Also add another `WHERE end < current-unix-time` in the subquery to filter out unwanted past rows.